# Attendance List with checkboxes submission from jsp form to spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox

I am displaying list of students with checkbox each to take attendance for each student. The problem is I am unable to justify the iteration for checkbox it asking `items="${studentsList}"` is mandatory presently my part of JSP page looks like this

### .jsp

```
  <c:if test="${!empty studentsList}">
                    <c:forEach items="${studentsList}" var="student">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${student.studentId}</td>
                            <td>${student.studentName}</td>
                            <td>${student.fatherName}</td>
                            <td><form:checkboxes path="studentsListFlag" items="${studentsList}"/></td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
```

If I set `items="${studentsList}"` in checkboxes iteration total list is getting displayed in single checkbox column, can anybody please suggest me how to iterate the above list. I am working hard for this your suggestions will help me a lot.

Comment: Could you upload a snapshot of the params you post, and the declaration of the controller must handle these calls?

Comment: This is my form declaration in jsp                                                       <form:form commandName="attendanceCommandName" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/attendance"  method="post">        and my controller method is like this   @RequestMapping(value="/attendance", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAttendance(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("attendanceCommandName") @Valid AttendanceCommandName attendanceCommandName,BindingResult br,HttpSession session) { //...} I am unable to get updated list fron jsp to controller

Comment: Ouch, hard to read here in a comment with no format... could you edit your question adding this as well as AttendanceCommandName class?

Comment: @Nithin Can you post all the related codes, so that it will be easy to help you.

Comment: <c:if test="${!empty studentsList}">
                    <c:forEach items="${studentsList}" var="student">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${student.studentId}</td>
                            <td>${student.studentName}</td>
                            <td>${student.fatherName}</td>
                            <td><form:checkboxes path="studentsListFlag" items="${studentsListFlag}"/></td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>